# FileUsesReservedNameException when trying to create an app bundle

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I can create apk for my Android application but when I try to create a bundle to upload on to the Play Store, it fails and shows the error:

> `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.build.bundletool.exceptions.BundleFileTypesException$FileUsesReservedNameException: File 'root/res/values/values.xml' uses reserved file or directory name 'res'`

Comment: i updated your question title and some minor formatting, feel free to let me know if you do not approve of this and i'll undo it :)

Comment: you should also probably consider including your `values.xml` file

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you depend on an SDK or a library which contains resources but is packaged as a JAR instead of an AAR.

If packaged as a JAR, all the files (including resources) will be considered as assets and not actual Android resources. While the APK allowed this, the Android App Bundle detects that this is probably not what is intended and is likely to produce unexpected behaviours so prevents it.

You can read more about AARs here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library